# Generic methods with constraints that are generic

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

What I want to do is have a method that takes a generic type as a parameter with a constraint. However, the constraint's type also has a second generic type, but I want the method to work regardless of what the second typing is:

```
public class IEvent<T> where T : EventArgs { }
public class EventManager
{
    public void DoMethod<T>() where T: IEvent<???>
    {
    }
}
```

Specifically, I'm trying to have my `EventManager` class receive any kind of event and then do something with it. Am I overcomplicating things, or is this doable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use a second constraint:

```
void DoMethod<TEvent, TArgs>() where TEvent : IEvent<TArgs> where TArgs : EventArgs {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class IEvent<T> where T : EventArgs { }
public class EventManager
{
    public void DoMethod<T, U>() where T : IEvent<U> where U : EventArgs
    {
    }
}
```